# Remove last punctuation of a swift string

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

I'm trying to remove the last punctuation of a string in swift 2.0

```
var str: String = "This is a string, but i need to remove this comma,      \n"
var trimmedstr: String = str.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

First I'm removing the the white spaces and newline characters at the end, and then I need to check of the last character of `trimmedstr` if it is a punctuation. It can be a period, comma, dash, etc, and if it is i need to remove it it.

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.  You can use `contains` to check if the last character is in the set of expected characters, and use `dropLast()` on the `String` to construct a new string without the last character:

```
let str = "This is a string, but i need to remove this comma, \n"

let trimmedstr = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

if let lastchar = trimmedstr.last {
    if [",", ".", "-", "?"].contains(lastchar) {
        let newstr = String(trimmedstr.dropLast())
        print(newstr)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed my problem!

Comment: You're welcome @VitalikK. Please click the checkmark to the left of my answer to turn it green.

Comment: Got it, i'm just new to stack overflow

Comment: would you by any chance know how to initialize this Dictionary: `var songs = [String: [song]]()` where song is a structure

Comment: That is initialized. Song should be capitalized as a struct name. Post a new question with your structure and the data you want to put in your dictionary.

Comment: I posted it under "How to initialize a Dictionary with structure components in Swift"

Answer (score 3):

Could use `.trimmingCharacters(in:.whitespacesAndNewlines)` and `.trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters)`

for example, to remove whitespaces and punctuations on both ends of the String-

> let str = "\n  This is a string, but i need to remove this comma and whitespaces,      \t\n"
>
> let trimmedStr = str.trimmingCharacters(in:
>   .whitespacesAndNewlines).trimmingCharacters(in: .punctuationCharacters)

*Result* -

> This is a string, but i need to remove this comma and whitespaces